# Integration of Drupal 7 And Dspace

Tags: drupal-7, single-sign-on, dspace

I need to integrate DSpace with Drupal.

I've installed DSpace and use the XMLUI interface. It's working fine. Now I need to integrate it with Drupal and I also want to do employ a single sign-on system.

I have tried this [DSpace module for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/dspace) and followed the instruction given even, yet I am still not able to access the DSpace content.

Comment: Have you tried posting the dspace issue queue? It doesn't look like that project has much activity, or even a release, but asking there might be worth a shot. The question seems pretty broad to get any good answer here.

Comment: You may want to consider http://islandora.ca/.  Which integrates Dspace and Drupal.

Comment: @Natkeeran, islandora integrates Fedora Commons (not DSpace) and Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different components in your question:

**Single Sign on**

DSpace supports stackable authentication methods. Depending on which single sign on you wish to use, you may need to consider different approaches. The overall documentation on authentication methods can be found here:
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Authentication+Plugins

**Read-only operations on DSpace from Drupal**

DSpace 4 ships with a Jersey based REST API
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/REST+API

Based on this API, you could use Drupal modules like the following for the integration:
http://drupal.org/project/rest_client
http://drupal.org/project/clients

**Depositing content in DSpace from Drupal**

The aforementioned REST API does not support write operations yet. However, DSpace supports SWORD 2, a very elaborate standard for facilitating Deposit.

I am not sure if there is a working Drupal module for SWORD 2 deposit. I found an older one here:
http://drupal.org/project/sword

The SWORD 2 Spec itself can be found at:
http://swordapp.org/

Comment: Updates to Bram's answer:
DSpace 5 now has a read/write REST API: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/REST+API